# Python how to make all elements on a list be of a certain length

Tags: python, format, tabular

I am trying to make sure that no matter the length of the elements on a list I have, only the first X characters are displayed when I do an output.

For instance if I had:

```
DATA = 
Column1 Column2 Column3
ABCD    1234    5678
FGHI    0987    6543
ABCDEFGH135791011   3545455
```

I would like that last line to only select the first 7 characters so I can print:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 
ABCD    1234    5678 
FGHI    0987    6543 
ABCDEFG 1357910 3545455
```

I will miss some text and number but will have the main data in a readeable format.

Also, this is not about "How to do a substring". I know that if `A = 'abcdefg'` I can simply do `A[:5]` to get the first 5 characters. What I want is to do that on a list without having a nested "for". (yeah one could simply build a FOR each IN ... and create a new table with each elemented being trimmed). I am interested to know if there is an elegant "*Pythonic*" way of doing that.

Thanks!

Comment: PLease be more precise... And add code youve tried

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = "ABCDEFGH135791011"
>>> print s[:7]
ABCDEFG
```